# Вывод значений переменных в зависимости от option value

Tags: php, html, dropdown

Мне нужно чтобы при выборе варианта из выпадающего списка (Sensor 1 и Sensor 2) в ячейку таблицы подставлялись определенные значения. Написал код, однако он не работает. Прошу подсказать в чем ошибка.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>

<style>

td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sensors.php">
<select name="eventid" id="eventid">
<option value="0" dissabled>Choose</option>
<option value="1">Sensor 1</option>
<option value="2">Sensor 2</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

$eventid = isset($_POST['eventid']);
$type = "";
$element = "";


switch($eventid){
case "1":
$type = 0;
$element = 2;
break;  

case "2":
$type = 70;
$element = 1;
break;

default:
echo 'Error';
}

?>

<table width="200" height="100">

<tr>

<td> <?php echo $type  ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $element  ?> </td>

</tr>



</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: isset() возвращает true, а не $_POST['eventid']

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>

    td {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sensors.php">
    <select name="eventid" id="eventid">
    <option value="0" dissabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Sensor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Sensor 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>

<?php

$type = 0;
$element = 0;

if(isset($_POST['eventid'])){
    $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
    switch($eventid){
        case "1":
            $type = 0;
            $element = 2;
            break;  

        case "2":
            $type = 70;
            $element = 1;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Error';

    }
}

?>

<table width="200" height="100">

    <tr>

        <td> <?php echo $type  ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $element  ?> </td>

    </tr>
    


 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```